# field don't accept Arabic word in nickname

Tags: php

this is a code for guest user ,
he can enter chat with just nickname , in English word work and no problem ,
but in Arabic word get this message ( Error : Invalid Input or Field Empty )
when Enter Arabic word with number 1 or 2 or any number it will done and username 1_randon_string .
where is the error ?
so did need more coded ?
I'm have little known of php .
thanks for all .

```
 <?php
include 'fns/filters/load.php';
$result = array();
$result['success'] = false;
  $result['error_message'] = Registry::load('strings')->invalid_value;
$result['error_key'] = 'invalid_value';
$result['error_variables'] = ['nickname'];
$noerror = true;
$strict_mode = true;
if (Registry::load('settings')->non_latin_usernames !== 'enable') {
$strict_mode = false;
}
if (!isset($data['nickname'])) {
$noerror = false;
} else {
$data['username'] = sanitize_username($data['nickname'], $strict_mode);
if (empty(trim($data['username']))) {
    $noerror = false;
 }
}
if (Registry::load('settings')->guest_login !== 'enable') {
$result['error_message'] = Registry::load('strings')->went_wrong;
$result['error_key'] = 'something_went_wrong';
$noerror = false;
}

if (!Registry::load('current_user')->logged_in) {

 if (isset(Registry::load('settings')->captcha) && Registry::load('settings')->captcha !== 'disable') {
    include 'fns/captcha/load.php';
}
if (isset(Registry::load('settings')->captcha) && Registry::load('settings')->captcha === 'google_recaptcha_v2') {
    if (!isset($data['g-recaptcha-response']) || empty(trim($data['g-recaptcha-response']))) {
        $result['error_message'] = Registry::load('strings')->invalid_captcha;
        $result['error_variables'][] = 'captcha';
        $noerror = false;
             } 
   else if (!validate_captcha('google_recaptcha_v2', $data['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        $result['error_message'] = Registry::load('strings')->invalid_captcha;
        $result['error_variables'][] = 'captcha';
        $noerror = false;
      }
   } else if (isset(Registry::load('settings')->captcha) && Registry::load('settings')- 
 >captcha === 'hcaptcha') {
    if (!isset($data['h-captcha-response']) || empty(trim($data['h-captcha-response']))) {
        $result['error_message'] = Registry::load('strings')->invalid_captcha;
        $result['error_variables'][] = 'captcha';
        $noerror = false;
    } else if (!validate_captcha('hcaptcha', $data['h-captcha-response'])) {
        $result['error_message'] = Registry::load('strings')->invalid_captcha;
        $result['error_variables'][] = 'captcha';
        $noerror = false;
      }
   }
}

if ($noerror) {
$guest_user = [
    'add' => 'site_users',
    'full_name' => $data['nickname'],
    'username' => $data['username'],
    'password' => random_string(['length' => 6]),
    'signup_page' => true,
    'return' => true
];

if (username_exists($data['username'])) {
    $guest_user['username'] = $data['username'].'_'.random_string(['length' => 5]);
}

$guest_user['email_address'] = $guest_user['username'].'@'.random_string(['length' => 5]).'.guestuser';

if (isset($data['redirect'])) {
    $guest_user['redirect'] = $data['redirect'];
}
$result = add($guest_user, ['force_request' => true, 'exclude_filters_function' => true, 'guest_user' => true]);
 }

 ?>
```

this is function sanitize_username :

```
function sanitize_username($username, $strict = false) {
$username = strip_all_tags($username);
$username = remove_accents($username);
$username = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', 
$username);
$username = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $username);

if ($strict) {
    $username = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9 _.\-]|i', '', $username);
}

$username = str_replace(array('\'', '"', ',', '@', ';', '(', ')', '[', ']', '<', '>', '{', '}', '?', '&'), '', $username);
$username = trim($username);
$username = preg_replace('|\s+|', ' ', $username);
$username = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $username);
return $username;
}
```

Comment: Probably something from `sanitize_username`,  but you don't show that

Comment: what need to do for that please ? what must edit ?

Comment: Show us that function, and we might be able to help.

Comment: sorry what you mean please ? any function you want ?

Comment: Show the `sanitize_username` function, that is what is checking the characters of the username.

Comment: ok , I  added it above .

Comment: Walk through that function. First it strips all the tags from the username, then all the accents. Then it replaces any character that is not A-F or 0-9 (those characters are for hex codes, so is even stripping out most of the latin/English characters). Then it removes more and more and more characters. I'm surprised you end up with anything useable at all.

Comment: what must doing ?

Comment: Check the value of `Registry::load('settings')->non_latin_usernames`, it should not be `enable`. That is what is stripping everything on `$username = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9 _.\-]|i', '', $username);`

Comment: I do all that , but not work .